# Elasticsearch Unique Results

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, faceted-search

Is there someway in elasticsearch to adapt the following query so that it only produces unique results. For example I have the following data:

```
Name | Age | Height
--------------------
John | 10  | 4'6
John | 11  | 4'8
John | 12  | 4'10
John | 12  | 4'11
Adam | 12  | 4'12
```

I want to adjust the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     }, 
     "terms": {
        "field": "name"
     }
}
```

So that it returns the following:

```
Name | Age | Height
--------------------
John | 12  | 4'11
Adam | 12  | 4'12
```

Also, how can I adjust it to group by two fields?

Comment: Can you please explain more , What is your expected output. If above two result is your expected output then I have question , what basis you need to group this result?. e.g `John | 12  | 4'11` is result for `john` age `12` then you have one more record in matching criteria `John | 12  | 4'10` ..

Comment: I would want to have two options (can be queried separately). The first would group based on just name. The second would group by name and age.